# Why my hands are thin and stomach has a lot of fat

Tags: weight, hand, stomach

Even though I eat a lot food, my hands are very thin but I have a pot-belly.  I eat 3/4 KG of rice daily which is more than normal but I still don't gain weight in my hands.

What could be the cause of this?

Please don't suggest to do hand related exercises because I see that most people don't do exercises, yet still gain weight in their hands.

Comment: Hello. Asking for a diagnosis specific to your individual condition is something we really can't manage in this format. If you would like to re-frame it as a general question about weight distribution, please feel free to [edit] and flag so that we can see about re-opening. Thanks.

Comment: did you got any solution to make your hands fat and reduce belly fat ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People tend to gain weight around the abdomen and hips because we generally have many more millions out fat cells in those areas and very few in the hands. It is possible to gain weight in your hands, but it is *not* possible to target weight gain in *only* your hands. Weight gain and weight loss happens systemically; that is, that your entire body gains and loses weight at the same time in proportion to the amount of fat cells in that part of your body.

As for the disproportionate amount of fat cells in your abdominal region compared to your hands, I'm afraid you are just built that way.

Comment: to add, I **think** malnutrition could be the cause of fat in belly, and having thin hands [here](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=malnutrition+in+africa&view=detailv2&&&id=070B622133A559F45CBA31AF150BEA04D02158A5&selectedIndex=31&ccid=jsewWCKA&simid=607987556562832002&thid=JN.bRekuBJX38YnZegS3ZRSpQ&ajaxhist=0)

Comment: @servantofWiser, that isn't fat in the belly, it is water.  When there is a lack of protein in the blood because of poor diet, the blood leaks out into abdomen causing it to distend.  A similar thing can happen in liver disease if the liver fails in making adequate proteins, in particular albumin.